# EF Creating optional relation using fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

These are my classes:

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Department_Id")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Manager_Id")]
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

    [Column("Parent_Department_Id")]
    public int? ParentDeptId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> ChildDepartments { get; set; }

    public virtual Department ParentDepartment { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Employee_Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("First_Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Last_Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Job_Title_Id")]
    [ForeignKey("JobTitle")]
    public int? JobTitleId { get; set; }

    [Column("Manager_Id")]
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Department_Id")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now in Department the Manager is optional. How can I build this relation using fluent api? I figured I need to use `modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasOptional(e => e.Manager)` but can't figure out what should follow next. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I already have this piece of code for my Department if that makes any difference:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ChildDepartments)
            .WithOptional(e => e.ParentDepartment)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentDeptId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish that relation

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasOptional(e => e.Manager).WithOptionalDependent();
```